# "Un-bundling" Pyinstaller exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm having trouble reducing the size of the exe that's being created with Pyinstaller.

I'm able to successfully pack everything into one .exe, but it ends up ~52MBs and on slower computers, takes almost a minute to start. I tested adding a `print('hello')` to the top of my code, and saw that it's not my code that's slow to start, it's the unpacking of the .exe that's taking forever. Here's a list of what I'm importing:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import boto3
import keyring
import requests
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from pandas import read_csv
from tkinter import filedialog
from keyring.backends import Windows
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
```

From what I understand, instead of creating one file, and having the .exe unpack everything every time, I should create a directory with dependencies already unpacked. However, I'm having trouble getting the pyinstaller settings right to accomplish this.

My one-file .spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['AppstreamUserManager.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Desktop\\Appstream-User-Manager'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('.\\images\\icon.gif','.'),
             ('.\\images\\search.gif','.'),
             ('.\\images\\refresh.gif','.')],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone','win32cred'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          Tree('.\\images',  prefix='images\\'),
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Appstream User Manager',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          icon='.\\images\\icon.ico'
            )
```

This gives me the ~52MB .exe.

I tried using the following to create a directory instead:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['AppstreamUserManager.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Desktop\\testing'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('.\\images\\icon.gif','.'),
             ('.\\images\\search.gif','.'),
             ('.\\images\\refresh.gif','.')],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone','win32cred'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          Tree('.\\images',  prefix='images\\'),
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Appstream User Manager',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          icon='.\\images\\icon.ico'
          )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='AppstreamUserManager')
```

I do end up with a directory, and unpacked dependencies, but the .exe itself is still ~52MBs and takes roughly the same amount of time to start. I think what's going wrong is the `a.datas`, `a.binaries`, etc that I'm adding to the .exe. I don't know how to safely remove them though.

I tried removing `a.datas` and the .exe shrunk, but I got the following error:

```
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171202'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\testing\dist\AppstreamUserManager\Appstream User Manager.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Desktop\\testing\\dist\\AppstreamUserManager\\Appstream User Manager.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Desktop\\testing\\dist\\AppstreamUserManager\\Appstream User Manager.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\Emilio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI171202\\base_library.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\Emilio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI171202',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001b20 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

I tried removing `a.zipfiles` and nothing changed.

I tried removing `a.binaries` and the .exe shrunk, but I got the following error:

```
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI179162\python38.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, because I clearly see python38.dll in the pyinstaller `dist` directory.

I tried removing `a.scripts`, and, as expected, the program does not run. Funnily enough, it's still ~52MBs.

What can I do to reduce the .exe filesize, and hopefully reduce the time needed to start?

Thanks!

Edit: I should mention I'm using:

```
PyInstaller      4.0.dev0+a1f92c6a08
Python           3.8.1 64-bit
Windows 10       64-bit
```

Edit 2: I have added `'scipy','matplotlib','PIL','cython','PyQt4','zmq','sqlite3','lib2to3'` to the list of excludes, and this brought the .exe down to 38.5MBs. The .exe still takes a long time to start though, and I'm not sure how to find more modules that I can safely exclude. The only thing I want from pandas is read_csv, but I think pyinstaller is packaging way more than that — and the same for the other imports.

Comment: Are you using a Virtual environment? Then you only need to bundle the packages you need for your specific application into Pyinstaller. You won't need to manually figure out what to exclude. Also, if you only need Pandas for `read_csv` why not just use `csv` from the standard library instead?

Comment: @wstk That's a good point, thanks. I've switched from Pandas to `csv` and my exe is down to 33MBs. Loading speeds did improve, but still aren't great. I'm not sure how using a virtual environment would help — is a basic Python installation bundling extra packages? I'm not using anaconda or anything. I would still like to figure out how to get this working as a onedir setup though.

Comment: The thought behind the venv was you mentioned having to manually add various packages to the 'exclude' list. With a venv you could only install the packages you needed in your environment, and so wouldn't have to worry about doing this.
As for another point - you mentioned that *the actual .exe file* is ~ 33 MB, not the size of the whole directory. Is this right?

Comment: I had to manually add some packages to the exclude list because my imports were importing more than they needed (for example, Pandas was importing matplotlib, which I didn't need). In a virtual environment, if I import a package like Pandas, it would not import unused dependencies? And yes, currently the actual .exe file is ~33MB.